# Functions in azure functions not showing up

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm working on a app as part of univeristy project. I set up github actions to deploy the app. The action completes succesfully, but in azure, after opening the function, there are no functions listed under functions->functions tab (the table is empty).

The repo is available at:
https://github.com/TomasMadeja/pa200-project-covid-registrations

Answer (score -1):

​**Functions in azure functions not showing up**

try creating a pre-compiled Azure function by using following pipelines

**npm install**

- Working Folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

**dotnet build**

- Arguments: --configuration Release

**Archive files**

- Root folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1
- Archive type: zip
- Archive file to create: (Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/(Build.BuildId).zip
- Replace existing archive: true

*Note your root folder structure may be different for the path to your /bin folder. Adjust accordingly.*

**Azure Function App Deploy**

- (Select your subscription, app type and name)
- Package or folder: **(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/(Build.BuildId).zip**

The key here for me was to understand that pre-compiled Azure functions require a specific folder structure, as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#functions-class-library-project. Getting the folder/file structure is necessary to allow your functions to show in the Azure portal.

Therefore structure in the `/wwwroot` folder looked something like this:

```
| - bin  

| - MyFunction  

| - host.json
```

for further information you can go through the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105855/azure-functions-not-showing-up-in-function-app-in-portal#:%7E:text=Yet%20another%20solution%20for%20not%20showing%20%28deploying%29%20functions,fixed%20the%20issue.%20Deleting%20App%20Service%20Application%20settings.)